# inpage anchor tags not working using markdown

Tags: html, markdown

I have some markdown that looks like this:

```
* [a](#a)
* [b something](#b-something)
    * [c](#c)
    * [d e f g](#d-e-f-g)
```

and then some `h2` tags with anchors:

```
## <a name="#a"></a>a
## <a name="#b-something"></a>b something
## <a name="#c"></a>c
## <a name="#d-e-f-g"></a>d e f g
```

And they generate the markup nice but the hash anchor don't navigate to the right part of the page

Anyone know why? There is a live version of the example [here](http://aklp.gr/how-to-drain-every-single-drop-of-juice-out-of-sublime-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` attribute must not contain the `#`

```
## <a name="a"></a> a
```